# Sort images by sequence

Tags: python, sorting

Hello I'm trying to sort my microscpoy images.
I'm using python 3.7
File names' are like this. t0, t1, t2

```
S18_b0s17t0c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif
S18_b0s17t1c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif
S18_b0s17t2c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif
.
.
.
S18_b0s17t145c0x62672-1792y6689-1024
```

I tried "sorted" the list but it was like this

[image]

can some one give me some tips to sort out by the sequence

Comment: What do you mean "sort by the sequence"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to extract the integers in the filename, this should solve the issue of 100 coming before 2.

```
files = ['S18_b0s17t100c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif','S18_b0s17t1c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif','S18_b0s17t2c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif']

sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(re.findall('S\d{1,2}\_b\ds\d{1,2}t(\d+)',x)[0]))
```

Output

```
['S18_b0s17t1c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif',
 'S18_b0s17t2c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif',
 'S18_b0s17t100c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use lambda function do define the sorting key for `sorted` function

```
lst = ["S18_b0s17t0c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif", "S18_b0s17t1c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif", "S18_b0s17t2c0x62672-1792y6689-1024.tif" , "S18_b0s17t145c0x62672-1792y6689-1024"]

sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda filename: filename[10:].split('c')[0])
```

Comment: This will return varying length strings, which will not sort properly if I understand the OP request.